Why is casting a union member pointer to a union pointer not UB as they can have different size?
In the following code snippet, a buffer-overflow occurs, namely when doing u->b = *b;.
class A {
public:
  int x;
  A() {
    x = 5;
  }
};

class B {
public:
  int x;
  float y;
  B() {
    x = 10;
    y = 3.14;
  }
};

union U {
  A a;
  B b;
};

U* foo(U* u) {
  B* b = new B();
  u->b = *b;
  return u;
}

int main() {
  A* a  = new A();
  U* u = (U*) a;
  u = foo(u);
  return u->b.y;
}


From what I read here, the cast (U*) a should be well defined. To my understanding it should not be as sizeof(U) != sizeof(A).
It's seems that U and A are pointer-interconvertible but I'm unsure if this implies that the cast is well defined.
I'm having trouble following the standard in this case, any help would be welcome!
*** EDIT ***
I do not plan to use this code but seen people activate a union in this way. For example here

afaik the cast is ok, what you do with the pointer in your code is not.

"From what I read here, the cast (U*) a should be well defined." pointer-interconvertibility means if there are two objects already there, casting and using the pointer as if it's a pointer to another is valid.

Why can't people just accept that using (untagged) unions in C++ is just a bad idea.
https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#p4-ideally-a-program-should-be-statically-type-safe

U* u = (U*) a;, but a does not actually point to U object, so how could that be fine? Also, the question should be clear without clicking external links, so maybe edit with more details.

Also note that you are effectively using reinterpret_cast<U*>(a) here. So please tell us, what do you expect to happen here?

That a there is clearly not pointing at union member so I do not understand how the posted code has any relation to "casting union member pointer to union pointer".

actually the answer already says "This means that you can convert them to each other using reinterpret_cast. However, you cannot access the memory of wrong type.", cast is ok, pretending it would point to something it does not point to is not ok

@PepijnKramer no worries, not gonna use it anywhere. More a theroetical question as I seen these kind of cast used elsewhere and wondered if the cast itself is correct or not.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I do not access the memory as the wrong type as I activate the union with type B. What you imply is that this is type confusion already, aka the cast is unsafe?

a points to an A. A is not a union. You then cast that pointer to a different type that the pointer does not point to.

the only object you create in this code is of type A. There is no union of which you could access any member

None of the conditions in the answer you linked hold in your situation, so your conclusion is puzzling.

a pointer alone doesnt make a valid pointee. The answer exaplains that if you create an object of right type you can also access it, but only then

I think you've misinterpreted the convertibility rules to apply to types, but they say "Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if [...]" (my emphasis). Also, the sizes have nothing to do with convertibility.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm mostly wondering at which point does this program breaks the security guarantees: at cast time, at access time? To me it looks like a type confusion. Does pointer-interconvertibility implies a type-safe conversion? I guess not?

It's well defined because sizeof(U*) == sizeof(A*).  The usage dereferencing the pointer to the wrong type is not okay, but that doesn't appear to be relevant to the question.  (Which is why this code crashes on my machine.)

@vwvw Mostly I am not so worried when people use the "language-laywer" tag (correctly). But other people read the comments as well, and... well you know ;)

Objects of type U are pointer-interconvertible with their subobject U::a. This can be tested with std::is_pointer_interconvertible_with_class(&U::a).
(U*) a is reinterpret_cast<U*>(a). This is static_cast<U*>(static_cast<void*>(a)), where [expr.static.cast]p14 says:

Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an object a, and there is an object b of type similar to T that is pointer-interconvertible with a, the result is a pointer to b.

There might not be an object of type U at that address, meaning you don't get a pointer to a U, just a pointer with type U pointing to *a.
Subsequently accessing it like a U is undefined behaviour (for obvious reasons, given in [basic.lval]p11). So u->b = *b; is undefined behaviour.

However, it is possible that this could avoid UB. The operator new call can return more bytes than requested ([basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]p2, [new.delete.single]p3), and operator new implicitly creates object ([intro.object]p14), and std::is_implicit_lifetime_v<U>. That operator new call could allocate enough bytes to store a U object, in which case it would implicitly create the U, making this well formed.
A more standard way to do that would be this:
A* a = static_cast<A*>(operator new(sizeof(U)));
U* u = reinterpret_cast<U*>(a);
u = foo(u);
return u->b.y;

Which explicitly avoids that size problem you were worried about.

Thanks for the detailed answer. Can we also conclude that such a cast is a type confusion as it violates type-safety? If I got it right, a type-safe program should always have objects with valid types for the underlying memory.
Can you do anything else with u apart from casting it back to A as accessing is unsafe?

This suggested more standard way works on my machine, as I'd expect.  Worth understanding how this language feature works, and then avoid using it except when necessary, and consider std::variant instead.

Re: "it is possible that this could avoid UB" -- the behavior is undefined because the C++ standard doesn't tell you what it does. That doesn't change if operator new happens to allocate enough bytes for the code to do what someone expects it to do.

@PeteBecker because there can be multiple implicitly created objects, if you get enough memory from new, the standard does tell you what happens: *a is the A subobject of a U, and is pointer-interconvertible with the implicitly created U object

@Caleth -- citation, please? "could allocate" is not a term of art in the C++ standard. The code creates an object of type A and then says "pretend that this is actually a B. "Pointer-interconvertible" says that they have the same address; it doesn't make that conversion valid.

@PeteBecker reinterpret_cast is allowed to cast between pointers that point to pointer-interconvertible objects. Those casts being valid is the purpose of  pointer-interconvertible

@Caleth -- the cast is valid; that doesn't make stomping on the memory valid. See all of the comments to the question.

@PeteBecker the cast is valid iff there is a U there, i.e. if the allocation was of at least sizeof(U) bytes

@PeteBecker We actually had this exact discussion, does a type confusion occurs when an object is cast to the incorrect type or only if some elements of this illegal cast are accessed.

@PeteBecker: Casting a union-member type to a union type and then accessing that same member either through the union or via memcpy (with the same size as the member) may fail if the union contains any types whose alignment is coarser than the member.  Such failure is easily demonstrable with clang, targeting the Cortex-M0.
